# Matplotlib annoying square in right top corner

Tags: python, matplotlib

May be this is a silly question. I am exporting an eps plot from matplotlib (installed through Anaconda in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS). When opening the .eps file an annoying square appears at the right top corner, this seems to be something from the fig viewer. I still could not manage to find a solution.

[image]

EDIT: I am adding the code, after the accepted answer.

```
plt.figure(num=2, figsize=(5,3))
p1, = plt.plot(ffaa[0], ffaa[1], 'k-', linewidth=0.5) 
plt.xlabel('Time (s)',   fontsize=8)
plt.ylabel('Voltage (V)',fontsize=8)
plt.legend(handles=[p1]) 
plt.xlim([0,100])
plt.show()
mu.figexp('Figure 03 - Frequency spectrum', plt)
```

Comment: Looks like where the legend would go.  Do you have `legend=None` in your plot command?

Comment: What is your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "annoying square" is a `legend`. So at some place in your code you create a legend for your graph, presumably via `plt.legend()` or `ax.legend()`. However your plot does not have any label associated with it. Hence the legend stays empty.

Solutions:

- Remove the line that created the legend from your code.
- Add a label to your plot, e.g. via `plt.plot(...., label="my label")`, which would then be shown inside the box.

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest ! I have deleted the line and it works, it is surprising that under a similar installation of Anaconda in Windows I was not having the problem of the empty legend.

Comment: One can only find out the reason if knowing which versions are installed in both installations.